# Org-ref: how to get absolute path of bibliography in exported LaTeX file

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-ref

I use Org-ref to insert references in Org mode when writing articles.
I prefer to put bib files in a separate place, say `/bib/ref.bib`, instead of putting together with org files in `~/org/`. After inserting references with absolute path `bibliography:/bib/ref.bib`, I exported the Org file to LaTeX file by `C-c C-e l l`. However, the bibliography in the exported LaTeX file is specified by relative path, `\bibliography{../../../bib/ref}`.

How to get bibliography with absolute path `\bibliography{/bib/ref}` in the exported LaTeX file?

The reason I want to use absolute path is that the exported LaTeX file may be copied to other location and compiled. In that case, I have to manually change the relative path. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A feature to set absolute path for bib file has been merged in org-ref. Update org-ref and add `(setq org-ref-latex-bib-resolve-func #'expand-file-name)`.
See org-ref github issues [here](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/pull/762) and [here](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues/732).